# incluir archivo de texto en la carpeta dist

Tags: java, netbeans

¿hay alguna manera de que en la carpeta dist (al hacer clean and built) me incluya un fichero de texto necesario para que funcione el programa en netbeans? Es que me veo obligado a copiarlo a mano cada vez que genero la carpeta dist al hacer el built. Quiero que el archivo de texto se añada en la raiz del proyecto.
Estoy utilizando "apache netbeans ide 14" y estoy utilizando ant para construir el proyecto. Y este es el codigo del archivo build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for -->
<!-- some examples of how to customize the build. -->
<!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) -->
<!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. -->
<!-- Commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use this build script if -->
<!-- the Compile on Save feature is turned off for the project. -->
<!-- You can turn off the Compile on Save (or Deploy on Save) setting -->
<!-- in the project's Project Properties dialog box.-->
<project name="pesca1.6" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project pesca1.6.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. They are: 

      -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
      -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
      -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
      -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
      -pre-compile-single:       called before javac compilation of single file
      -post-compile-single:      called after javac compilation of single file
      -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -pre-compile-test-single:  called before javac compilation of single JUnit test
      -post-compile-test-single: called after javac compilation of single JUunit test
      -pre-jar:                  called before JAR building
      -post-jar:                 called after JAR building
      -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

    (Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

    Example of inserting an obfuscator after compilation could look like this:

        <target name="-post-compile">
            <obfuscate>
                <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            </obfuscate>
        </target>

    For list of available properties check the imported 
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 


    Another way to customize the build is by overriding existing main targets.
    The targets of interest are: 

      -init-macrodef-javac:     defines macro for javac compilation
      -init-macrodef-junit:     defines macro for junit execution
      -init-macrodef-debug:     defines macro for class debugging
      -init-macrodef-java:      defines macro for class execution
      -do-jar:                  JAR building
      run:                      execution of project 
      -javadoc-build:           Javadoc generation
      test-report:              JUnit report generation

    An example of overriding the target for project execution could look like this:

        <target name="run" depends="pesca1.6-impl.jar">
            <exec dir="bin" executable="launcher.exe">
                <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
            </exec>
        </target>

    Notice that the overridden target depends on the jar target and not only on 
    the compile target as the regular run target does. Again, for a list of available 
    properties which you can use, check the target you are overriding in the
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 

    -->
</project>
```

Comment: si tu proyecto es de tipo ant, en vez de maven o gradle, en tu script xml de ant agrega `<copy file="mi_archivo.txt" tofile="dist/mi_archivo.txt" />` despues de que veas algo tipo `<mkdir dir="dist" />`

Comment: Debes modificar la configuración que usas para construir tu proyecto (como te dicen, con gradle o maven). Dependiendo de eso, será un archivo pom.xml o .gradle. Dependiendo de eso, puedes recibir una respuesta adecuada. Revisa cómo estás construyendo tu proyecto y pon ese archivo aquí en tu pregunta yendo a [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Sí, hay varias formas en las que puedes incluir un archivo de texto en la carpeta dist cuando haces un clean and built en Netbeans. Una opción es agregar el archivo de texto a la carpeta de origen de tu proyecto en Netbeans, de modo que se incluya automáticamente en la carpeta dist cuando haces un clean and built.

Otra opción es usar un script ant o maven que se ejecute durante el proceso de construcción y copie el archivo de texto en la carpeta dist. Puedes agregar un script ant o maven en Netbeans siguiendo estos pasos:

Haz clic derecho en tu proyecto en el panel "Projects" en Netbeans y selecciona "Properties".
En la ventana que se abre, selecciona la pestaña "Build" y luego haz clic en el botón "Customize".
En la ventana que se abre, haz clic en el botón "Add" y selecciona "Copy files" en el menú desplegable.
En la ventana "Copy files", establece la carpeta de origen donde se encuentra el archivo de texto que deseas incluir en la carpeta dist y establece la carpeta destino como "dist".
Haz clic en "OK" para guardar los cambios y cierra la ventana de propiedades del proyecto.
Ahora, cada vez que hagas un clean and built en Netbeans, se ejecutará el script ant o maven que has creado y copiará el archivo de texto en la carpeta dist.

Comment: No se sabe si el OP usa Ant, Maven o Gradle. Preguntas incompletas terminan en malas respuestas como ésta. Incluso si se usa chatGPT.

Comment: ¿Sabes que te van a cerrar la cuenta por usar chatGPT?

Comment: actualmente estoy utilizando ant.Con respecto a la respuesta de  Peteco, no me aparece la opcion customize al pulsar en built.

Comment: @raposo no ignores los comentarios a tu pregunta y amplíala.